# Problem with scale app icon in Blazor .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, icons, maui

I have a file ico, which size is 256x256. I set this file as MauiIcon. Problem is image extends beyond app icon on Android (does not scale).

How can I fix it?

I've tried to set attributes BaseSize and resize (on true or false), but it didn't help.

Comment: Is your icon file a svg or a png? And did you try to use the [ForegroundScale property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?tabs=android#platform-specific-configuration)?

Comment: This is propably because of the adaptive icon (Android 8+), try to set the `ForegroundScale="0.65"` in the MauiIcon config.